# Audio transcription with word-level time-resolution accuracy

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, transcription

The usual transcription softwares (manual or automated) only give you the time-resolution (not sure if the right word) of one sentence or a group of words at least, for example:

```
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:03,000
- How did he do that?
```

What I want is a transcription that gives you time-resolutions for each word, for example:

```
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,500
- How
00:00:00,500 --> 00:00:01,000
- did
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:02,000
- he
00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:02,500
- do
00:00:02,500 --> 00:00:03,000
- that?
```

Or better yet, gives me the control of how many words (max) I want in a single line.

I even have the (regular) transcripts generated already, so I might not even need the software to actually do transcription itself (although not a problem if it'll need to do it anyway) but just need it to correctly give me the word-level time-resolution accuracy.

Is there such a software?

- Windows/Linux/Web
- Trial/shareware

Comment: It may be worth looking a karaoke software/libraries for this - usually a line or phrase is shown at any one time but with the highlight moving with a word, (or smaller), resolution.